# Dymola warning about derivatives of noEvent

Tags: warnings, derivative, dymola

In the Dymola translation log of one large model I see several times the warning:

```
Warning: Can only compute non-scalar gradients of functions specifying derivatives and not for:
  noEvent
```

with no indication of where it comes from. Could someone explain what the warning means, and how to find and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any message of that kind should only occur if you have set the flag `Advanced.PrintFailureToDifferentiate = true;` if you set this flag to false it should not occur.

The likely cause is that you have a non-scalar expression involving `noEvent` that for some reason needs to be solved using a system of equations; and it just means that Dymola does not yet generate analytic Jacobians for such systems.

The exact cause is difficult to say without the model; you could send that through the normal support-channels.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the flag PrintFailureToDifferentiate is set. I cannot submit the model unfortunately, it is a large customer model. Is it possible to find the nonlinear block where this occurs? Or do I need to check all blocks?

Comment: It should be a non-linear system with numeric Jacobian that may help in narrowing it down. Large customer models can be sent through the support channels, but I understand that NDAs etc make it complicated; and an alternative is to hope there will be time to correct the underlying issue and/or improve the error message.